# Razor binding view to viewModel

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I m using a template that allow users to choose the color they prefer and many other things.
it's look like that:
[image]

Top Bar Color

```
        <ul class="clearfix" id="topBar_style_switch">                
            <li class="@Model.Color_0" title="topBar_style_0"><span class="icon_check_alt2"></span></li>
            <li class="@Model.Color_1" title="topBar_style_1"><span class="icon_check_alt2"></span></li>
            <li class="@Model.Color_2" title="topBar_style_2"><span class="icon_check_alt2"></span></li>
            ....
        </ul>
```

Fixed layout:

```
 <div class="clearfix hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-xs sepH_b">
        <label>Fixed layout</label>
        <div class="pull-right">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.IsFixedLayout, 
             new { @class = "js-switch mini-switch", @id = "fixed_layout_switch" })
            @if (Model.IsFixedLayout)
            {
                <script>
                    $('body').addClass('fixed_layout');
                    $('#fixed_layout_bg_switch').show();
                </script>
            }
            else
            {
                <script>
                    $('body').removeClass('fixed_layout');
                    $('#fixed_layout_bg_switch').hide();
                </script>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

the class css of the tag "li" change after click on the color, from '*sw_tb_style_x*'    **to**    '*sw_tb_style_x style_active*'.
I couldn't get the value of the color choosing in the action post, but i do get the value of the checkbox 'FixedLayout',
Is there a better way to implement it or how to get the value of color chooses after click in save button

Thanks!

Comment: This is far too broad for SO. Personally I would be using view models and radio buttons for the colors (and styling the buttons and associated label) but you could also include a hidden input for the color property and handle the `.click()` event of each color swatch to update the inputs value.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke for your comment, it helps me

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me well,

```
<ul class="clearfix" id="topBar_style_switch">
    @foreach (var color in Model.Colors)
    {
      <li id="@color.ID" class="@color.CssClass" title="@color.Title">
      <span class="icon_check_alt2"></span></li>
     }
     @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.IdSelectedTopBarColor, new { id = "selectedTopBarColor" })
</ul>


 // top bar style
   $('#topBar_style_switch li').on('click', function () {
        var topBarStyle = $(this).attr('title');
        $('#topBar_style_switch li').removeClass('style_active');
        $(this).addClass('style_active');
        $('#main_header').removeClass('topBar_style_1 topBar_style_2 ...').addClass(topBarStyle);            
        $("#selectedTopBarColor").val(this.id)            
    });
```